# How do I solve it with a monotonic stack?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack

I am solving a question "Steps to Make Array Non-decreasing" on LeetCode [here](https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-295/problems/steps-to-make-array-non-decreasing/).  Question is:

> You are given a 0-indexed integer array nums. In one step, remove all elements nums[i] where nums[i - 1] > nums[i] for all 0 < i < nums.length.  Return the number of steps performed until nums becomes a non-decreasing array. 
> Input: nums = [5,3,4,4,7,3,6,11,8,5,11] 
> Output: 3

During the contest I got the intuition to solve it using a monotonic stack.  I tried to solve it by keeping track of the next greater element (`nge`) and previous greater element (`pge`) for each element as below:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int totalSteps(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n=nums.size();
        vector<int> nge(n), pge(n);
        stack<int> stk, stk2;
        
        for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
            while(stk.size() && nums[stk.top()]<nums[i]) stk.pop();
            nge[i]=stk.size() ? stk.top() : n;
            stk.push(i);
        }

        int res=0;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) {
            res=max(res, nge[i]-i-1);
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            while(stk2.size() && nums[stk2.top()]<nums[i]) stk2.pop();
            pge[i]=stk2.size() ? stk2.top() : -1;
            stk2.push(i);
        }

        int ans=0;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) {
            ans=max(ans, i-pge[i]);
        }

        return min(res,ans);
    }
};
```

However it continues to yield wrong answers.  Any tips on how I could solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, not sure about the myth.  I solve those problems because I love solving them.

Comment: That's good to hear. Everyone needs a good hobby, to spend some free time on, that otherwise doesn't have much practical use. I tender after some house plants, and I love doing that to. What does this do for me? Just some personal satisfaction.

Comment: There are two parts, reduce the arran, and loop until done (counting iterations). Split your code into functions for each (the outer loop calls the reducing function). The simplest strategy is two vectors, scan values from one and copy them to the second, skipping those to be removed (remember [5,4,3] will remove 4 *and* 3). Swap the vectors and do the next step. If any were skipped, count that, stop when none have been removed.

Comment: @JohnBayko, could you please elaborate?  Some code snippet would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a simpler algorithm like the one suggested by John Bayko. But, to make it fun, when thinking about algorithms I usually try to find the most appropriate standard library tools to compose them. So, here's how I might start with a short function to find the next iterator in nums to copy from, given a "current" iterator:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <ranges>

int totalSteps(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    namespace rng = std::ranges;

    auto nextOne = [&nums](auto current) {
        return rng::adjacent_find(current, nums.end(), rng::greater{});
    };

    // ...
}
```

Is this suggestive enough?